# How to get key.id() in unicode format

Tags: google-app-engine, unicode, app-engine-ndb

I want to show chinese url for the pages that are in chinese language.

the Key class is returning id() as a str.

```
pages = Page.query().fetch()
for page in pages:
   type(page.key.id())
   >> <type 'str'>
```

I'm using the entity Id to store the url of the page. All was ok until I want to use chinese inside my urls. Since the page.key.id() does not returns unicode Jinja makes an error at decoding.

```
{%- for page in pages %}
<a href="/admin/page/{{ page.key.id() }}">{{ page.key.id() }}</a>
{%- endfor %}
```

gives :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

However, the SDK Console/Datastore viewer is perfectly able to show the chinese string as the entity ID.

Is it a mistake or wrong usage of gae to use the entity ID as a url ? 
Should I change my design or is there a way to make my current design work ?

Comment: Hi Cyril, Were you able to figure out how to use unicode characters (like Chinese) in entity id ? If yes, please let us know how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your template file (somefile.html) is stored in UTF-8 encoding, not as a plain text file, when saving in your text editor.  (For example, in Save As dialog, choose UTF-8 encoding)

Also, you will want something like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in your template's HEAD tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have no problem to display unicode content when it comes from a StringProperty or a TextProperty, and I can see that in that case ndb returns a unicode python string. I think the problem is related to the key.id() return type.

Comment: Do you have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your `views.py`?  Can you explain the minus signs in your jinja tags `{%-`?  I have not seen those used before.  Your error is still telling you that your template is using ascii decoding.

Comment: Actually the project itself can be seen [here](https://github.com/daseeds/pennsylvania), although not the latest version. I've got the heading you mention on top of all py files (though I dont have a views.py). for the last thing, it's just telling jinja not to add a LF when resolving the template.

Comment: When I open admin_main.py, I see that it is encoded is Western (ISO-8859-1).  Same for admin_base.html.  They need to be in UTF-8

Comment: Which tool are you using for that ? Sublime Text editor tells me the files are saved with utf8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be to get the `urlsafe()` Key representation [mentioned in the docs here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/keyclass).  In your template, you'd just change `page.key.id()` to `page.key.urlsafe()`.

To then fetch your Page entity using that key, you'd use `Key(urlsafe={value generated above}).get()`